# Use ajax to display a form depending on an input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've designed a website using wordpress, - On my site I want to show a booking system which is organised by postcode (So I stay in the same area on the various days).

I've written some php code which allows me to input a postcode, it then removes any whitespace and removes the last 3 characters. Whats left is checked against a list of postcodes and depending on what the postcode is, it displays different forms...

this is the code:

```
<?php
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$postcode = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $postcode);
$postcode = substr($postcode, 0, -3);

    if(in_array($postcode, array("NR1", "NR2", "NR3", "NR4", "NR5", "NR6", "NR7", "NR8", "NR9", "NR19", "NR20"))){
?>
[bookly-form staff_member_id="2" hide="staff_members,date,week_days,time_range"]
<?php
    } elseif(in_array($postcode, array("NR10", "NR11", "NR12", "NR26", "NR27", "NR28"))) {
?>
[bookly-form staff_member_id="3" hide="staff_members,date,week_days,time_range"]
<?php
    } elseif(in_array($postcode, array("NR13", "NR14", "NR15", "NR29", "NR30", "NR31", "NR32", "NR33", "NR34", "NR35", "IP18", "IP19", "IP20", "IP21", "IP22"))) {
?>
[bookly-form staff_member_id="4" hide="staff_members,date,week_days,time_range"]
<?php
    } else {
?>
Thank you for enquiring about our microchipping services. Unfortunatly we don't cover your postcode at the moment.
If you'd like to know when we do cover your area simply fill out the form below or feel free to call our offices to register your details

[ccf_form id="57"]
<?php
    }
?>
```

Considering this is in wordpress, I can use a php plugin to either call the code etc and manually code the form in html - but how would I get this to run through ajax so that I do not need to submit the page etc... I don't want the page to refresh - I just want the content to swap.

Comment: You can use jquery.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.
Try it, if you will have some issues you won't be able to fix post the question.

Comment: just a tip, instead of a bunch of "or"s in your conditional, just use `if(in_array($postcode, array("NR1", "NR2", "NR3"))){...}`

Comment: @Pamblam - Thank you, that smartened up the code :)

Comment: any ideas how to get this fed in to an ajax query?

Answer (score 1):

Initial form for postcode in your html file:

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" value="" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>;
<div id="return-wrap"></div>
```

On submit serialize data for sending. ( console.log(); is for debugging and you can see result in browsers console )

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.status);
            $('#return-wrap').html(data.result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
            console.log(data.status);
        }
    });
});
});
```

And then access data in php like you would access any other post data

```
if($_POST){

    $template = $_POST['postcode'];

    /** Do whatever with this data */ 
    $form = '';
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ok', 'result' => $form));

} else {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error'));
}
```

Comment: Hey @user2831723 , I wrote this question out, but for some reason there was a load of info about wordpress missing - Is this still valid?